# I can not install sign apk in physical device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am having problem installing apk-release.apk in my phone its saying installer has stoped couldnt install on physical device

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

Disable the Instant Run, Clean the project and try again.

i had the same problem, so this maybe can help.

Comment: Its still not running same problem